# Ajax calls are not working in cordova (6.3.0 ) application with Rest API

Tags: java

I am building cordova (6.3.0 ) application with Rest API but ajax call are not working.
I'm using Cordova 6.3.0 and AJAX requests from Android devices don't work. I've already read and tried anything useful I could find and I am not able to solve this problem myself.

I'm using a jquery ajax request to call a server that returns plain text

```
$("#rest").click(function(){


     $.get('http://localhost:2016/RESTfulExample/rest/registration/test',{firstname:'phani'},function(data,status) { 


           $("#hai").html(data);

});
```

Comment: Try to debug using a console and show us the error message. It can be anything

Comment: are you able to launch this web service from browser? try using fiddler to see whether your request is working fine or not.